# How to import win32 for Python on mac

Tags: python, email, outlook, pywin32

I am trying to read email coming to my outlook mailbox and saw that win32 was a popular option however when I try to install it, I get -

```
~ pip install pywin32
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pywin32 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pywin32
```

I am using Python 3.7.2 with MacOS Big Sur 11.1

I am looking for either another extension that has the ability to read mail from outlook or a way to instlall pywin.

Comment: **You can't** use *PyWin32* (and even if you could, by doing some tricks, **you shouldn't**). Check the *doc*s, especially supported *OS*, it only works on *Win*. https://pypi.org/project/pywin32.

Comment: https://pyoutlook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#